# NullPointerException when assigning numbers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, autoboxing

There is a strange thing happening when I execute the following code:

```
private void doStuff(Long inLong) {
    long theNumber = inLong;

    /* ... */
}
```

Sometimes I see a NullPointerException in the logs at the assignment line and I can't understand why it happens. Any idea?

Comment: If the input can't be `null` then use `long`.

Answer (score 2):

You passed in null.  Check what you are passing in.

Answer (score 2):

For `long theNumber = inLong;`, the long value of inLong is fetched by implicitly calling `inLong.longValue()`. This is called auto-unboxing (sometimes more general auto-boxing). When inLong is null, you therefore get a NullPointerException just like calling any other method on null.

Therefore, you should think of some alternative:

If you do not need an undefined value, you should make sure the caller never passes null and assert this via:

```
private void doStuff(Long inLong) {
  assert inLong != null; 
  long theNumber = inLong;
  /* ... */
}
```

(or use a [Nonnull-Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker)). If the method were public and you cannot be sure that null is not passed, rather do:

```
public void doStuff(Long inLong) {
  if (inLong == null) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); } 
  long theNumber = inLong;
  /* ... */
}
```

If you neither need undefined values nor use the value in a collection (or in any other generic parameter), rather use the method `private void doStuff(long inLong)` instead. If you do need a Long object, you can, of course, still use the parameter of type `long` and do (auto-)boxing inside of `doStuff` to get an according Long object.

If you do need undefined values, you should check for it and do what is necessary:

```
private void doStuff(Long inLong) {
  if (inLong == null) { 
    handleUndef(); 
  } else {
    long theNumber = inLong;
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Just setting the value to 0 instead of some more elaborate `handleUndef()` is dubious in my opinion, because then you could have used the parameter of type long (see above) in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

inLong is probably `null`. Then you try to assign a `null` reference and unbox it into a primitive type.

Comment: Just tried to assign a Long with value 'null' to a long on my machine, just to be sure. It does indeed cause a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

because `inLong` can be null and will not be automatically mapped to 0.
I guess what you want to do is this:

```
theNumber = 0; // or Long.MIN_VALUE or Long.MAX_VALUE or whatever you prefer
if (inLong != null) {
    theNumber = inLong;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think mapping to 0 would be the appropriate solution in this case...

Comment: That's why I guessed :)  I normally use `MIN_VALUE` or `NaN` for invalid numbers but it highly depends on the context.

Comment: MIN_VALUE or MAX_VALUE is not that much different of 0 - you could just have used the parameter long instead (see my answer below). using NaN is better, but then you have to handle null in a completely different way anyways to avoid another exception...

Answer (score 0):

That's because the inLong parameter is null.
Whenever you assign a `Long` object to a `long` variable, Java automatically tries to unbox it to the proper type, but it fails if value of the Long variable is null.

Just put a null-check before that assignment and you'll get rid of that error, but you may have to raise an exception or deal with the null argument appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

if inLong is null, then NPE is the expected behaviour.

```
long theNumber = inLong;
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
long theNumber = inLong.longValue();
```

which should make the cause of the NPE obvious.